# MongoDB Codec in Scala broken?

Tags: mongodb, scala

I have an app written in Scala to access a Mongo database in which I can query and insert data perfectly fine.

However when I try to use `collection.distinct("user")` I get the error:

```
Unknown Error org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException:
    Can't find a codec for class scala.runtime.Nothing$.
```

After doing some googling I found that I would need to specify a codec, so I initalised the `MongoClient` with one:

```
val clusterSettings = ClusterSettings
    .builder()
    .hosts(scala.collection.immutable.List(new com.mongodb.ServerAddress(addr)).asJava)
    .build()

val settings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
               .codecRegistry(MongoClient.DEFAULT_CODEC_REGISTRY)
               .clusterSettings(clusterSettings)
               .build()

val mongoClient: MongoClient = MongoClient(settings)
```

Still no luck, got the same error.

I figured I would need to make a custom codec [as per this web page](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/bson/codecs/):

```
class NothingCodec extends Codec[Nothing] {
    override def encode(writer:BsonWriter, value:Nothing, encoderContext:EncoderContext)={}
    override def decode(reader: BsonReader, decoderContext: DecoderContext): Nothing = { 
        throw new Exception
    }
    override def getEncoderClass(): Class[Nothing] = {
        classOf[Nothing] 
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work nor doesn't make sense, Nothing is not a valid return type; [there exist no instances of this type](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.1/scala/Nothing.html).
As a result this obvisouly does not work with a new error of `Unknown Error java.lang.Exception`(Obviously!)

**Am I missing something with the Mongo Scala Driver? Or is it just broken?**

Comment: Or you can have a look at http://reactivemongo.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Document instead:

```
collection.distinct[Document]("user")

// i.e. 

case class User(name: String, id: String)

records.distinct[Document]("user")
.toFuture()
.map(_ map { doc => getUserFromBson(doc).get })

def getUserFromBson(doc: Document): Option[User] = {
 for {
   name <- doc.get("name") map { x => x.asString().getValue }
   id <- doc.get("id") map { x => x.asString().getValue }
  }yield(User(name, id))
}
```

hope this helps.